# Is [insert] a meta tag, and should be replaced by more specific ones?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, meta-tags

The tag [insert](/questions/tagged/insert) wiki states:

> A data entry mode. An example would be new data typed on the keyboard
> to be inserted at the current cursor location on screen.

For me it sounds like a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) because it is too vague to be used as **only** tag in the question. If it can apply to inserting row into SQL table, inserting cell into Excel sheet or inserting a few characters into HTML TextArea, how could it function without other tags?

According to the cited article of Jeff Atwood, such meta tags should be burninated.

Is the [insert](/questions/tagged/insert) tag such meta tag, and should it be destroyed or replaced by more specific tags, such as [sql-insert](/questions/tagged/sql-insert), [dom-insert](/questions/tagged/dom-insert) or [text-insert](/questions/tagged/text-insert)?